# How to not just add a new first column to csv but alter the header names

Tags: python, csv

I would like to do the following
read a csv file, Add a new first column, then rename some of the columns
then load the records from csv file.
Ultimately, I would like the first column to be populated with the file
name.
I'm fairly new to Python and I've kind of worked out how to change the fieldnames however, loading the data is a problem as it's looking for the original fieldnames which no longer match.

Code snippet

```
import csv
import os
inputFileName = "manifest1.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_modified.csv"
with open(inputFileName, 'rb') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'wb') as outfile:
    r = csv.DictReader(inFile)
    fieldnames = ['MapSvcName','ClientHostName', 'Databasetype', 'ID_A', 'KeepExistingData', 'KeepExistingMapCache', 'Name', 'OnPremisePath', 'Resourcestype']
    w = csv.DictWriter(outfile,fieldnames)
    w.writeheader()
```

*** Here is where I start to go wrong

```
# copy the rest
for node, row in enumerate(r,1):
    w.writerow(dict(row))
```

Error
    File "D:\Apps\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
        + ", ".join([repr(x) for x in wrong_fields]))
    ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: 'Databases [xsi:type]', 'Resources [xsi:type]', 'ID'

Would like to some assistance to not just learn but truly understand what I need to do.

Cheers and thanks
Peter

Update..
I think I've worked it out

```
import csv
import os
inputFileName = "manifest1.csv"
outputFileName = os.path.splitext(inputFileName)[0] + "_modified.csv"

with open(inputFileName, 'rb') as inFile, open(outputFileName, 'wb') as  outfile:
r = csv.reader(inFile)
w = csv.writer(outfile)

header = next(r)
header.insert(0, 'MapSvcName')
#w.writerow(header)

next(r, None)  # skip the first row from the reader, the old header
# write new header
w.writerow(['MapSvcName','ClientHostName', 'Databasetype', 'ID_A', 'KeepExistingData', 'KeepExistingMapCache', 'Name', 'OnPremisePath', 'Resourcestype'])

prevRow = next(r)
prevRow.insert(0, '0')
w.writerow(prevRow)
for row in r:
   if prevRow[-1] == row[-1]:
       val = '0'
   else:
       val = prevRow[-1]
   row.insert(0,val)
   prevRow = row
   w.writerow(row)
```

Comment: What line in the lines you are showing us is generating that error? Also you may want to dynamically generate the field names based on what you find in the source file.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks the bit that goes wrong is where I try to write to the output file and to answer the second question, Because there are duplicate fieldnames when the csv file is created from the xml I'm trying to alter the fieldnames basically to overcome this issue.

Comment: # copy the rest
    for node, row in enumerate(r,1):
        w.writerow(dict(row))

Comment: Though it looks like you may have worked out your own problem, I'd strongly recommend using pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this sort of thing in the future if your file can be loaded into memory. CSV import and export are pretty simple, as is changing columns, performing operations on rows, etc.